# Hosting a Unity2D game on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-web-app-service, unity-webgl

I am trying to deploy my unity2D video game to Azures web app.

I load up my Unity game and build it as a webGL. Once I did that I got these files. [image: Once I did that I got these files.]

Next I had to add a web.config file to the main folder.

I can't figure out what to put into the web.config.
The 3 web.config's I've tried are:

```
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>

        <staticContent>

            <remove fileExtension=".json"/>

            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>

            <remove fileExtension=".unityweb"/>

            <mimeMap fileExtension=".unityweb" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>

        </staticContent>

    </system.webServer>

    <system.web>

        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

[image: And this.]

And this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/vnd.unity" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)